# A question on $G=S_5$ concerning notation

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, notation, symmetric-groups

I think there must be a misprint in a question I've been asked.It has written on it ;

$$|G|=S_5$$

but of course this notation is nonsense as a real number cant be equal to a set.

Do you think it was supposed to read

i)$|G|=|S_5|$

ii)$G=S_5$

I also have the additional question that if $|G|=|S_5|$ then can we assume that G is isomorphic to $S_5$ and still consider the elements of G to be permutation cycles ?

Comment: If $G=S_5$, then of course $|G|=|S_5|$ but it is not true the other way. For example, $|\Bbb{Z}_{120}|=|S_5|$ but of course they are neither the same group nor isomorphic. Without knowing the context of the question I cannot be sure but I would go with that the problem was supposed to be $G=S_5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably like you wrote it, i.e $G = \mathcal{S}_5$.

$|G| = |\mathcal{S}_5|$ doesn't imply that $G = \mathcal{S}_5$, since there are 47 groups of order 120 up to isomorphism.

Comment: Yes I think you are right I saw that later the number of 5-cycles in G was discussed in the problem set so a solid giveaway